# Invalid hook call - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Developing teams application using react - I am trying to use Ag grid react to design sample table. I have added code and while running it it throws errors as follows.

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Below the code snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';

import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export default function Project() {
  return (
     <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 400, width: 600}}>  
         <AgGridReact>
         </AgGridReact>
       </div>
   )
};
```

Comment: There's not much here to go on. You might revise to list the versions of React and the components.

Comment: hey can you please check react and react-dom versions in package.json ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. React version - 16.14.0 & React dom - 16.14.0

Comment: in this the only component u have ?, if u have other components please add them in the question section

Comment: No, I have added this code in index.jsx file.

Comment: Also if I remove <AgGridReact></AgGridReact> this tag then it works without any errors. when I add this piece of code its giving me "Invalid hook call".

Comment: ok cool try removing the {} from AgGridReact in import , if that doesnt work reinstall the AgGridReact package

Comment: Where is the hook being called?  Do you have a function somewhere that starts with `use`?

Comment: I don't have any hook calls to the logic like use statement..

Comment: Thanks Ahmed Honsy, Removing the {} from import solved my issue.

Comment: Hi Ahmed Honsy,   I don't think removing the curly braces will wont work. We need to add the curly braces if we export named components.  If I remove this curly braces its throw me different error. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Tab

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to the duplicate version of react in the application folder - deleting the node_module folder and ran npm install solved my issue.